# Calling Sharepoint Web Service in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF service. I created a simple asp.net web application and called a SharePoint Admin web-service to create a site. Following is the code.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateSiteClass objCreateSiteClass = new CreateSiteClass();
        objCreateSiteClass.CreateSite(txtSiteName.Text);
    }

[WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "AdminSoap", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")]

public class CreateSiteClass : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    public void CreateSite(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            AdminService.Admin admService = new AdminService.Admin();
            //admService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            admService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ashish.rautela", "badri@12345", "IRISSOFTWARE");
            admService.CreateSite(str, "Title", "Description", 1033, "STS#0", "IRISSOFTWARE\\ashish.rautela", "Ashish Rautela", "ashish.rautela@irissoftware.com", "", "");
        }
        catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

This successfully created the site (whatever you will pass in the function parameter)

But my requirement is to use this service inside an WCf service. So, i created a WCF application and wrote the same function in my Service1 class that implements the IService1 interface.

The WCF service was build successfully and when i browsed it after creating a virtual directory it gave me the following path:-

http://vm-sp-vishal.irissoftware.com:8888/WCFSiteCreateor/Service1.svc?wsdl

After this i created a simple asp.net web application and added a service reference in my project by right clicking-->Add service Reference. Then i wrote the following code in my default.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestService(txt.Text);
}

protected void TestService(string strUrl)
{
    MyWCFAdminService.Service1Client objMyWCFAdminService = new MyWCFAdminService.Service1Client();
    objMyWCFAdminService.SiteCreatorClass(strUrl);
}
```

But when i run this application and pass the function parameter into an textbox, it gives me a access denied error.

I am a farm administrator member in the SharePoint server where i am running this code.

Any help?

Comment: what user account does the  wcf service run under? does it have the necessary access to do the sharepoint related processes? Try creating a separate app pool and set the required identity to that pool.(considering that you have hosted the WCF in IIS)

Comment: The user account it is using is a member of the farm administrator group member. It does have the necessary access to the SharePoint process as it ran successfully without calling the same snippet inside WCF. I believe my WCF service is not having the write operation rights on SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you need to sort out your access policies as you will be going cross domain ...

you may need a clientaccesspolicy.xmlm file in the root of your wcf services (or the sdharepoint ones)

its contents need to be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from>
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Obviously that one is not secure ;) ill le tyou figure that bit out.